# Definition: Sum of two vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

this definition is correct:

definition: let $(E;+_E;\cdot_E)$ a vector space, and $F,G$ two vector subspaces of $E$, the "sum of vector subspaces $F$ and $G$" is the set $ \{v \in E | v= t +_E r$ and $t \in F$ and $r \in G \}$.
Is it correct?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes. Note it is the subspace generated by $F\cup G$.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff... thanks soo much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that definition is correct.  Another equivalent definition is that the sum of the vector subspaces $F$ and $G$ is the smallest subspace of $E$ that contains both $F$ and $G$.